# VB.NET | Read Binary Off Registry?

Tags: vb.net, binary

I'm trying to read a value off my registry but its REG_BINARY. It can only read REG_SZ from what I've tested.

```
MsgBox(My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("PATH", "Name", Nothing))
```

How do I read Binary off my registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wzw8xe3w.aspx) is declared to return `Object`. To read a binary value, you should just cast the result:

```
Dim value as Object = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("PATH", "Name", Nothing)
Dim bytes as Byte() = CType(value, Byte())
```

Comment: How would I turn this into a string?

Comment: @Necro.: That depends on what you want the result to be. Binary? Hex? Base64? Is it actually an encoded string already? It's impossible to answer without more information.

Comment: I'd just like to make it readable. As for now I have 

Dim str As String
        Dim enc As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
        str = enc.GetString(bytes)

but it returns unreadable text.

Comment: @Necro.: Well yes, it would. What's the data meant to represent? Use `BitConverter.ToString(bytes)` to get a hex string...